# ruby fill elements of an array into a set of nested arrays and remove duplicates

Tags: ruby

I have the arrays **months** and **monthly_doc_count_for_topic**.

```
  months = ["2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01"]
  monthly_doc_count_for_topic =  [
    ["foo","2019-02-01: 186904","2019-03-01: 196961"],
    ["bar","2019-01-01: 8876","2019-04-01: 8694"]
  ]
  goal = [ 
    ["foo","2019-02-01: 186904","2019-03-01: 196961","2019-01-01","2019-02-01","2019-03-01","2019-04-01"],
    ["bar","2019-01-01: 8876","2019-04-01: 8694","2019-01-01","2019-02-01","2019-03-01","2019-04-01"]
  ]
```

I'd like to fill in element of the array **months** into arrays inside **monthly_doc_count_for_topic** so it looks like array **goal**.

My attempt:

```
  monthly_doc_count_for_topic.map do |topic_set| 
    months.each { |month| topic_set << month }
  end
```

But I'm getting:

```
=> [
  [0] [
    [0] "2019-01-01",
    [1] "2019-02-01",
    [2] "2019-03-01",
    [3] "2019-04-01"
  ],
  [1] [
    [0] "2019-01-01",
    [1] "2019-02-01",
    [2] "2019-03-01",
    [3] "2019-04-01"
  ]
]
```

it's not appending the values from monthly_doc_count_for_topic instead replacing it with elements from array months. How can I modify my code to achieve the output like array goal? Thank you very much!

Comment: It appears you want `monthly_doc_count_for_topic.map { |topic_set| topic_set + months }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland but this triples the elements of months into the nested sets

Comment: Oh, I was wrong! Your code works perfectly fine! @CarySwoveland Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it as solution? Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempt replace

> monthly_doc_count_for_topic.map

with

> monthly_doc_count_for_topic.each

and it works perfectly fine:

```
goal = monthly_doc_count_for_topic.each do |topic_set|
  months.each { |month| topic_set << month }
end
```

But I'd prefer CarySwoveland's solution in the comment, it's less verbose:

`monthly_doc_count_for_topic.map { |topic_set| topic_set + months }`